# Is the answer for $\lvert z-1\rvert = \lvert z+1\rvert , z = 0 + iy$ and are my steps correct?

Tags: complex-numbers

For an exercise with complex numbers we have to find all the z $\epsilon$   $\mathbb{C}$ with $\lvert z-1\lvert$ = $\lvert z+1\lvert$... I get this and want to check if it is correct:

$ z = x + iy$

$\lvert (x+iy) -1\lvert$ = $\lvert (x+iy) +1\lvert$

$\lvert (x-1)+iy\lvert$ = $\lvert (x+1)+iy\lvert$

$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}$ = $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}$

$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1+y^2}$ = $\sqrt{x^2+2x+1+y^2}$

$x^2-2x+1+y^2 = x^2+2x+1+y^2$

$-2x = 2x$

$0 = 4x$

$x = 0$

With this $\lvert z-1\lvert$ = $\lvert z+1\lvert$ would be right for all

$z = 0+iy$

Is that correct and could one simplify the answer? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You can also think about it geometrically.

The complex numbers $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|z - 1| = |z - (-1)|$ are precisely those which are at the same distance from the points $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. This is the same set as the ordinate axis.

Comment: Ok, thank you, would those be the complex numbers within circle with radius =1 ? And if so , I have some trouble understanding how they are the same with $z=0+iy$ because the last means somehow to me that the variable y could be bigger than 1, right?

Comment: When I talk about the ordinate axis, I mean the following set

$$\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2} \mid x = 0\}$$

which is exactly what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide so that there is only one absolute value. It's clear that $z=1$ is not a solution, so the equation is the same as $$1=\left\lVert\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right\rVert$$ and now to just have one "$z$":
$$1=\left\lVert1+\frac{2}{z-1}\right\rVert$$
So $1+\frac{2}{z-1}=e^{it}$. And you can use basic algebra to solve for $z$ and have a set of solutions as $t$ varies in $(0,2\pi)$. (I left out $t=0$ because that case gives no solution for $z$.)